# i2c-bus bindings error on RaspberryPi when developing an electron + Vue app

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, electron, i2c

I am developing an app based on ElectronJS and Vue which also makes use of the [i2c-bus library](https://github.com/fivdi/i2c-bus) for the MCP23017 I/O port expander. I have started a new vue-cli project and then installed the preceding library for the bus communication and the electron builder plugin through `vue add electron-builder`.
So far so good, no errors at compiling at all.
But when running `npm run electron:serve` to start my developing server and interact with i2c, I get an error in the following line of `i2c-bus.js` file inside my `node_modules/i2c-bus` directory:

Specifically in this line: `const i2c = require('bindings')('i2c.node');`
The error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modules' of undefined
    at Object.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:29)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:223)
    at Object../node_modules/bindings/bindings.js (chunk-vendors.js:34)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/i2c-bus/i2c-bus.js:4)     <-------- THE COMMENTED LINE
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/i2c-bus/i2c-bus.js:658)
    at Object../node_modules/i2c-bus/i2c-bus.js (chunk-vendors.js:141)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:854)
    at fn (app.js:151)
```

Any ideas?
No errors when installing packages, everything seems to be ok.
Thanks in advance.